# why i cant remove event using fullcalendar 5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar-5

I created a `calendar` `fullcalendar5` version 5, i add an `event` ,i show event in my `calendar` ,now i want to `delete event` but its give me error : `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function`.
also when i want to see `id` value its give me `undefined` .
i change code from `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);` to `event.remove()` but also not work.
i try also the see `event` value but its give me :
`{el: a.fc-daygrid-event.fc-daygrid-block-event.fc-h-event.fc-event.fc-event-draggable.fc-event-resizable…, event: EventApi, jsEvent: PointerEvent, view: ViewApi}`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AGENDA</title>
    <link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="https://findicons.com/files/icons/2805/squareplex/512/google_calendar.png">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootswatch@4.5.2/dist/flatly/bootstrap.min.css"
              crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.7.2/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
              integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w=="
              crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.13.1/css/all.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"
              integrity="sha512-63+XcK3ZAZFBhAVZ4irKWe9eorFG0qYsy2CaM5Z+F3kUn76ukznN0cp4SArgItSbDFD1RrrWgVMBY9C/2ZoURA=="
              crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js'></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-GDey37RZAxFkpFeJorEUwNoIbkTwsyC736KNSYucu1WJWFK9qTdzYub8ATxktr6Dwke7nbFaioypzbDOQykoRg=="
            crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    
       

</head>
<body>

<div class="container main">

    <div class="card mb-4 mt-3 p-2">
        <div id='calendar'></div>
    </div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      eventColor: 'orange',
      editable: true,

      events: [
        {
          id: '1',
          title: 'All Day Event',
          start: '2022-09-01',
        }
      ],

      eventClick: function(event){
                    id = event.id;
                    console.log(id);
                     if(confirm('Are you sure want to remove it?')) {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
                      }
                },

    });
    


    calendar.render();  
  });
</script>

</div>
</body>
    
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.7.2/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.7.2/locales-all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- DATATABLE -->
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src ="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src ="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src ="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.7.2/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.7.2/locales-all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use `event.event.remove();` instead

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AGENDA</title>
    <link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="https://findicons.com/files/icons/2805/squareplex/512/google_calendar.png">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootswatch@4.5.2/dist/flatly/bootstrap.min.css"
              crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.7.2/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
              integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w=="
              crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.13.1/css/all.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"
              integrity="sha512-63+XcK3ZAZFBhAVZ4irKWe9eorFG0qYsy2CaM5Z+F3kUn76ukznN0cp4SArgItSbDFD1RrrWgVMBY9C/2ZoURA=="
              crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js'></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-GDey37RZAxFkpFeJorEUwNoIbkTwsyC736KNSYucu1WJWFK9qTdzYub8ATxktr6Dwke7nbFaioypzbDOQykoRg=="
            crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    
       

</head>
<body>

<div class="container main">

    <div class="card mb-4 mt-3 p-2">
        <div id='calendar'></div>
    </div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      eventColor: 'orange',
      editable: true,

      events: [
        {
          id: '1',
          title: 'All Day Event',
          start: '2022-09-01',
        }
      ],

      eventClick: function(event){
                    id = event.event.id;
                    console.log(id);
                     if(confirm('Are you sure want to remove it?')) {
                        event.event.remove();
                        //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
                      }
                },

    });
    


    calendar.render();  
  });
</script>

</div>
</body>
    
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.7.2/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.7.2/locales-all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- DATATABLE -->
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src ="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src ="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src ="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.7.2/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.7.2/locales-all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```